# RSpec + DatabaseCleaner + PhantomJS: database get randomly erased during example with js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, phantomjs, rspec-rails

I have a simple scenario in my rspec feature:

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'CLIENT views results page' do
  context 'from welcome/index form' do
    let!(:location) { FactoryGirl.create :location, name: 'town' }

    before :each do
      visit '/'
    end

    scenario 'successfully', js: true do
      expect(Location.count).to eq 1

      fill_in 'from_address', with: 'Some address'
      fill_in 'to_address', with: 'Another address'
      click_button 'Search'

      expect(page).to have_content 'Some address → Another address'
    end
  end
end
```

**`spec_helper:`**

```
require 'rubygems'

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'factory_girl'
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

FactoryGirl.reload

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = true

  config.order = "random"
  config.tty = true
  config.mock_with :rspec
  config.filter_run focus: true
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

  config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, js: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"
Capybara.server_port = 9887 + ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'].to_i
```

And my scenario fails on some random step (after `expect(Location.count).to eq 1`) due to the fact, that there are no `Location` records:

```
(byebug) Location.all
[]
```

I think it might be one of two cases:

1. Either DatabaseCleaner cleans database before an example finishes
2. Or there are actually two threads with two databases, one of which (the one that is used by the app) is really empty

Gem versions:

- rspec (2.14.1)
- rspec-core (2.14.8)
- rspec-rails (2.14.0)
- phantomjs (1.9.7.1)
- rails (3.2.21)
- database_cleaner (0.9.1)

Comment: Are you sure, that your factory creates note witout any validation errors?

Comment: Yep, the example goes further `expect(Location.count).to eq 1`

Comment: `(byebug) Location.all → [#<Location id: 1, name: "town">]`

Comment: Try to move this location creation to your scenario block from "let!". And what happened after this?

Comment: @violarium, tried this one: http://pastie.org/private/6zbow8laznt26iuzyyvw Same behavior

Comment: So, does it mean, that when you create location inside of scenario, the next string **expect(Location.count).to eq 1** is not correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90628/discussion-between-violarium-and-installero).

Answer (score 0):

I remember having issues with this as well. My config for DB cleaning looks like this:

```
config.before(:each) do
  if Capybara.current_driver == :rack_test
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  else
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

Maybe it has something to do with the order your before blocks are called. So if `DatabaseCleaner.start` is called before you wanted strategy is set, you might see such results.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this issue by migrating to

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

instead of using `DatabaseCleaner`. Some [workarounds](http://www.spacevatican.org/2012/8/18/threading-the-rat/) are suggested to make transactional cleaning work with javascript tests. I chose this one:

(adding somewhere in the beginning of **`spec/spec_helper`**)

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  mattr_accessor :shared_connection
  @@shared_connection = nil

  def self.connection
    @@shared_connection || retrieve_connection
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
```

cause it seemed to work faster, still leaving some spontaneously failing tests (might not be the problem related to database).